# Mod Rewrite 500 Server Error issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Overview**

I'm trying to rewrite:

- `http://www.foo.com/bar` to the secure version `https://www.foo.com/bar`, then
- `https://www.foo.com/bar` to `https://www.foo.com/index.php?location=bar`

My `index.php` page simply outputs the `$_GET` variables.

**Code**

`.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA,R=permanent]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?location=$1 [L]
```

`index.php`:

```
<?php print_r($_GET); exit; ?>
```

**Issue**

1. If I visit `www.foo.com/bar`, I see a *500 Server Error*.
2. If I comment out the rule for handling the `$_GET` "location" variable and visit `foo.com`, it doesn't redirect to the secure version of the site.

---

**Update**

`.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if https is off (it is on)
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ ?location=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Visiting the following results in a redirect loop error:

- www.foo.com/bar
- www.foo.com/index.php?location=bar
- www.foo.com/?location=bar
- www.foo.com?location=bar

However, if I comment out this line:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

the page loads as expected:

> Array ( [location] => bar )

This leads me to believe that the issue lies with the HTTPS redirect, how can I solve this?

Comment: *"If I visit foo.com/bar"* - can you be more specific? as in if you're using `http://foo.com/bar` or `http://www.foo.com/bar`, those are 2 different animals. Doing `foo.com/bar` in a web browser, will default to `http://foo.com/bar` instead of `http://www.foo.com/bar`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've amended my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule is the problem:

```
RewriteRule ^https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA,R=permanent]
```

As syntax is

```
RewriteRule matching-pattern target [flags]
```

Also you need to `RewriteCond` in both rules to avoid rules looping.

You can fix it by replacing your code with:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

# if https is off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ ?location=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation; the first rule is now working, however if I visit `https://www.foo.com/bar` I get an error `ERR_REDIRECT_LOOP` saying there are too many redirects?

Comment: `/bar` is not a real directory, and there are no other rules.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have realised that it is the `https` rewrite rule that is causing the redirect loop - if I comment that line out, the page loads exactly what I am expecting

Comment: Not that I am aware of... where else would this rule be in place? I've amended my original question with an update for clarity

Comment: Open Chrome dev tool and disable caching. Then open `Networking` tab. Open `https://www.foo.com/bar` and see what `301/302` status URLs show up there.

Comment: Upon visiting `http://www.foo.com/bar`: *301 Moved Permanently* - *`https://www.foo.com/bar` Redirect*

Comment: Yes that is just one redirect and **correct one**. But if it is a redirect loop then are you seeing `301 Moved Permanently - https://www.foo.com/bar Redirect` repeatedly?

Comment: I was seeing it repeatedly; I fixed it by *uncommenting* the line `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`. Thanks!